# How to get dataFrame array value in a empty python array

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I am working with databricks dataframe(pyspark)

I have a dataframe that contains a array with string value.

I need to use the df value to assemble with value from a python array that i have.

What i want is to put the df value in a python array like this:

```
listArray = []

listArray.append(dataframeArrayValue)

print(listArray)
outPut:
     [value1, value2, value3]
```

The problem I get is that it kind off work, but for some reason I can not work with the string value that is added to the new array list(listArray).

My concept is that i am gonna build a url, where i need to use SQL to get the begining information of that url. That first part is what i put in the df array. For the last part off the url, i have that stored in a python array.

I want to loop through both array, and put the result in a empty array.

Something like this:

```
display(dfList)
outPut:
      [dfValue1, dafValue2, dfValue3]

print(pyList)
      [pyValue1, pyValue2, pyValue3]

Whant to put them together like this:

dfValue1 + pyValue2 etc..

And getting a array like this:

newArrayContainingBoth = []

-- loop with append
```

result:

```
print(newArrayContainingBoth)
outPut:
[dfValue1+pyValue1, dfValue2+pyValue2, dfValue3+pyValue]
```

Hope my question was clear enough

Comment: How did you loop?

Comment: Did you try? `newArrayContainingBoth  = dfList + pyList`

Comment: I have not made a loop jet. A problem is that from the df it looks like something like this: [value1, value2], but when i try to get the first element dfList[0], i get [value1, value2]. Idk why it is like that, cause   teoretical, it is supose to get me [value1] only. Sorry for bad english

Comment: On a note, are you sure? df = [value1, value2] and can you show some sample value df. Also, if you do python_list = df.collect(), all you have is list in python_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this steps,

- You can use `explode()` to get a `string` from that `array`. Then,
- **collect()** as `list`,
- Extract `string` part from the `Row`,
- `split()` by a **comma** (",").
- Finally, **use it**.

First import **explode()**,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
```

Assuming your context in DataFrame "df"

```
columns = ['nameOffjdbc', 'some_column']
rows = [
        (['/file/path.something1'], 'value1'),
        (['/file/path.something2'], 'value2')
        ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, columns)
df.show(2, False)
+-----------------------+-----------+
|nameOffjdbc            |some_column|
+-----------------------+-----------+
|[/file/path.something1]|value1     |
|[/file/path.something2]|value2     |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Select the column `nameOffjdbc` from DataFrame 'df'

```
dfArray = df.select('nameOffjdbc')
print(dfArray)
DataFrame[nameOffjdbc: array<string>]
```

## Explode the column `nameOffjdbc`

```
dfArray = dfArray.withColumn('nameOffjdbc', explode('nameOffjdbc'))
dfArray.show(2, False)
+---------------------+
|nameOffjdbc          |
+---------------------+
|/file/path.something1| 
|/file/path.something2|
+---------------------+
```

## Now collect it to newDfArray (This is a python list that you need).

```
newDfArray = dfArray.collect()
print(newDfArray)
[Row(nameOffjdbc=u'/file/path.something1'), 
     Row(nameOffjdbc=u'/file/path.something2')]
```

## Since, it is (will be) in the format `[Row(column)=u'value']`. We need to get the `value (string)` part of it. hence,

```
pyList = ",".join(str('{0}'.format(value.nameOffjdbc)) for value in newDfArray)
print(pyList, type(pyList))
('/file/path.something1,/file/path.something2', <type 'str'>)
```

## Split the value by a comma ",", which will create a `list` out of a `string`.

```
pyList = pyList.split(',')
print(pyList, type(pyList))
(['/file/path.something1', '/file/path.something2'], <type 'list'>)
```

## Use it

```
print(pyList[0])
/file/path.something1

print(pyList[1])
/file/path.something2
```

## If you want to loop

```
for items in pyList:
    print(items)
/file/path.something1
/file/path.something2
```

## In a nut shell the following code is all you need.

```
columns = ['nameOffjdbc', 'some_column']
rows = [
    (['/file/path.something1'], 'value1'),
    (['/file/path.something2'], 'value2')
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, columns)

dfArray = df.select('nameOffjdbc')

dfArray = dfArray.withColumn('nameOffjdbc', explode('nameOffjdbc')).collect()
pyList = ",".join(str('{0}'.format(value.nameOffjdbc)) for value in dfArray).split(',')
```

## NOTE: collect() always collects a DataFrame values into a list.

For more information, refer:

- **explode()**: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Comment: Thank you! It works nice! The only problem is when i got to your "Use it" step, my print looks like this: print(pyList[0])
[u'/file/path.something1'   Do you know why? Or does that not matter if it looks like that?

Comment: I dont want the [ u and '  to be a part off my string

Comment: Update: I fixt that porblem with .replace()

Comment: You need to follow every step and then use it.